# qplot factor by condition

Tags: r, bar-chart, ggplot2

Using this dataframe, `df`:

```
bat.condition bat.group      bat.money
1              safe          2825.882
2              safe          2931.875
1              glsa          6975.882
2              glsa          5407.500
1              studyabroad   3084.706
2              studyabroad   2253.750 
1              jcc           4134.706
2              jcc           5550.625
1              eagg          4578.824
2              eagg          5456.250
```

I would like to plot a bar chart with group on the x axis, money on the y axis.  Further, I would like the bars to be separated/factored by the condition in which they occur.  So far I have used the following code and it is nearly ideal.  I have the bars factored by group, I would just like to further factor it by condition.

```
qplot(factor(bat.group), data = df, geom = "bar", fill = bat.group, 
      weight = bat.money, position = "dodge")
```

Which produces the image seen here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generally get groupings with the `interaction` function:

```
 qplot(interaction(bat.condition, bat.group), data = df, geom = "bar", fill = bat.group, 
      weight = bat.money, position = "dodge")
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for - I hadn't searched the documentation for the term "interaction".  Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new variable to your dataframe and use facets like this:

```
df$factor = factor(df$bat.group)
qplot(as.character(bat.condition), data = df, geom = "bar", fill = bat.group, 
      weight = bat.money, position = "dodge", facets = . ~ factor)
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does what I think you are asking for. I have used `ggplot` syntax instead of `qplot`. I have used `facet_wrap` to separate your data by bat.condition. Also, `geom_barplot` needs the parameter `stat="identity"` or else it will try to bin your data.

```
# Using ggplot2 version 0.9.2.1
library(ggplot2)

dat = read.table(header=TRUE, 
text="bat.condition bat.group      bat.money
1              safe          2825.882
2              safe          2931.875
1              glsa          6975.882
2              glsa          5407.500
1              studyabroad   3084.706
2              studyabroad   2253.750 
1              jcc           4134.706
2              jcc           5550.625
1              eagg          4578.824
2              eagg          5456.250")


p1 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=bat.group, y=bat.money, fill=bat.group)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity") +
     facet_wrap(~ bat.condition)

ggsave(plot=p1, filename="plot_1.png", height=5, width=8)
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Using `fill=bat.condition` and adding `position="dodge"` will produce a figure like the one you have linked to in your comment.

```
p2 = ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=bat.group, y=bat.money, fill=factor(bat.condition)))+
     geom_bar(position="dodge")

ggsave(plot=p2, filename="plot_2.png", height=4, width=6)
```

[image]

Comment: That does look great.  I was wondering if it were possible to then have condition 1 and condition 2's values side by side per group.

Like this: http://www.jidesoft.com/images/bar-chart-group.png